# Multiple if razor syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Need your kind help on the razor syntax below as it is throwing error...

```
            <div class="container">
                        @{var i = 0;}
                        @foreach (var m in Tests)
                        {
                            if (i%3==0)
                            { 
                                <div class="row">
                            }

                            <div class="col-md-3">ass</div>

                            @if (i % 3 == 1)
                            {
                                </div>
                            }
                            @{i++;}
                        }

                </div>
```

> The using block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you
>   have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this
>   block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as
>   markup.

Then, I tried...

```
                <div class="container">
                        @{
                            var i = 0;
                            foreach (var m in Tests)
                            {
                                if (i%3==0)
                                { 
                                    <div class="row">
                                }

                                <div class="col-md-3">ass</div>

                                if (i % 3 == 1)
                                {
                                    </div>
                                }
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
```

but this give me...

```
ass  }if (i % 3 == 1) { 
ass  }if (i % 3 == 1) { 
ass  }if (i % 3 == 1) {
```

I appreciate help to correct my code...

Comment: looks like you should have `@` in front of the first `if`

Comment: @mrtig: Nope. It's at the top-level of a code block (`foreach`) and not wrapped in HTML tags. As a result, Razor will actually choke if you prefix it with an `@`. Though, I have always found this is ridiculous, as if Razor knows enough that it can tell me that I put an `@` where it wasn't needed, it should be able to just silently ignore it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Razor cannot properly match opening and closing tags if they are within separate code blocks, and as a result cannot properly parse the view. If you need to do something like this you either need to prefix the tags with `@:` to tell Razor to ignore parsing tags for that line or wrap them in `@Html.Raw`:

For example:

```
if (i % 3==0)
{ 
    @:<div class="row">
}
```

Or:

```
if (i % 3==0)
{ 
    @Html.Raw("<div class='row'>")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `@` from this `@if (i % 3 == 1)` and this `@{i++;}`. Both the expressions are already in the code block of: `@foreach (var m in Tests)`. Hence you don't need this `@`.